# PHP POST security

Tags: php, security, post

My web form is on a HTTPS page, has JavaScript validations and back end PHP validations checking for blank fields. The form works (sends email) and returns errors as expected.

I have gotten a blank email about once a day. The only thing I can think of is the POST is vulnerable.

How do you secure a POST action="URL" ? Or is this not vulnerable?

My form (Shortened):

```
<form id="itsp-form" method="post" action="http://www.website.com/save_itsp.php">
<label class="custom">Company name</label>
<input id="company_name" type="text" name="company_name" />
...           
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="errors"></div>
</div>
 <script>
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();

    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if (($("#company_name").val() == '') || ($("#type_of_business[]").val() == '')) {
       $("#errors").after('<span class="error">Please enter your Company name.</span>');
       hasError = true;
    }
  if(hasError == true) { return false; }
});
```

My PHP file:

```
function died($error) {
echo "We are very sorry, but there were blank fields found with the form you
   submitted. ";
$link_address = 'http://www.website.com/url/itsp';
echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>Click to Go Back<br/></a>";
die();
}

if (isset($_POST['company_name'])) 
{
$errors = "";

//validate and sanitize company name
if ($_POST['company_name'] != "")
{
  $_POST['company_name'] = filter_var($_POST['company_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
}
else 
died();

 /*****Email*****/
$to = "email";
$subject = "New ITSP Submission";
$message1 = "A new ITSP has submitted their information:
<br/>Company Name: " . $company_name . "
<br/>"; // . . .

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message1,$headers);
header("location: http://www.website.com/dir/itsp-confirmation/");
```

Comment: Are you sure that e-mail is blank vs. containing some invisible characters (such as space or non-breaking space)?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems a reasonable question and OP has clearly included code.

Comment: When reviewing the email, there is no white space.

Comment: +1 for reasonable question, one wrong downvote dosent change anything ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you check if it is `!=""` then you strip out all tags, so if it was HTML it would be `!=""` but after `filter_var` it would be `==""`.  So filter before you check for `!=""`.

```
//validate and sanitize company name
$company_name = filter_var($_POST['company_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if(empty($company_name))
{
    died();
}
```

Comment: I just noticed this as soon as I posted my answer. +1 to you for catching it.

Comment: @RezaSh: No, they have a custom `died()` function if you look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can really get through this is more than one space character in series. I suggest reviewing the length of the string that is posted back and ensure it is actually a zero length string before assuming it is empty.

Some email clients and even spam filtering systems will strip leading white space characters in emails to prevent the exploitation of certain bugs in spam detection systems.